# MYSQL - How do i fill a column in a database with 6 random varchar?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have to fill a column called "provicias" from a table "padron_filtrado" but this column "provincias" just can have this six variables:
"Heredia","San Jose","Cartago","Puntarenas","Alajuela","Limon","Guanacaste".
and i must have to fill it random.

I know how to make a rand of dates or numbers but not with varchars..

Comment: Use rand()/6 and use this in case statement to get one of these 6 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `elt()` function and `rand()` to do this:

```
update padron_filtrado pf
    set pf.provicias = elt(1 + floor(rand()*7),
                           'Heredia', 'San Jose', 'Cartago', 'Puntarenas', 'Alajeula, 'Limon', 'Guanacaste'
                          );
```

I counted seven values in your list rather than six.